# ASP.NET MVC renders only the custom control

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have been fighting this issue for over a week now and 20 developers can't figure out what is going on. I'm hoping someone here have seen this issue before.

Disclaimer: The website is a government site and it's password protected in a secured network, so unfortunately, I can't provide a link. But I'll try my best to explain as much as possible. If there is any particular code you want, I can provide it. I just don't want to clutter this question with a lot of useless code. SO here it goes.

- Environment: ASP.NET MVC
- Controls: Kendo Telerik
- Architecture: Layout > Views > Partial Views

The screen in question is the search result screen. When the application runs, it inherits a _SharedLayout. Inside this Layout (Master Page) is where the views are. In this case, the Search.vbhtml View. Up to this point, the page has no issues. The problem happens when I enter information in the search boxes and run the search button. The View connects to the database, and it returns the data but the _SharedLayout and Search View do not render. After inspecting the browser, I noticed the following

```
<html>
  <head> NOTHING HERE</head>
  <body>
      WHERE IS THE REST OF THE PAGE? LAYOUT AND SEARCH VIEW
      <div>
         Search result control forms and tables and all the good stuff 
      </div>
      FOOTER IS MISSING TOO
  </body>
</html>
```

And of course, without any references in the head of the page, the search results view is outputting styleless (as vanilla as it gets)

Here is the code for the search view (where the button that generates the results resides). Like I said above, if you need the controller code or anything else I'll do my best to provide it

```
@Modeltype IndividualSearchViewModel

@Code
   Layout = Nothing
   ViewData("Title") = "Search Individual"
   ViewData("PageName") = "Search Individual"
   Dim isPopupMode As String = "N"
   Dim ajaxAction = New AjaxOptions With {.HttpMethod = "post", .UpdateTargetId = "IndividualSearchContent", .InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace}

   If Not Model.Mode Is Nothing AndAlso Model.Mode.Equals("popup", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) Then
      isPopupMode = "Y"
      ajaxAction.OnBegin = "OnPopupRequestBegin('IndividualSearchContent')"
      ajaxAction.OnComplete = "OnPopupRequestComplete('IndividualSearchContent')"
   Else
      ajaxAction.OnBegin = "OnPageRequestBegin"
      ajaxAction.OnComplete = "OnPageRequestComplete"
   End If

   End Code

   <div id="IndividualSearchContent">
       @Using Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "IndividualSearch", ajaxAction, New With {.role = "form"})
       @<div class="searchCriteriaDivCss @(If(isPopupMode = "Y", "hidden", ""))">
       @Html.ValidationSummary(False, "", New With {.class = "text-danger"})
    </div>

    @<div class="form-horizontal">
         @If Model.Messages IsNot Nothing Then
             @<div id="ValidationMessages" class="form-group text-center">
                 @For Each message In Model.Messages
                     @<b>@message</b>
                     @<br />
                 Next
             </div>
             @<br />
         End If


    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(Function(m) m.IdentifierType, New With {.class = "col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"})
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                @Html.Kendo.DropDownListFor(Function(m) m.IdentifierTypeValue).HtmlAttributes(New With {.class = "form-control"}).BindTo(Model.IdentifierType).OptionLabel("Select One")
            </div>

            @Html.LabelFor(Function(m) m.Identifier, New With {.class = "col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"})
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                @Html.Kendo.MaskedTextBoxFor(Function(m) m.Identifier).Mask("#########").HtmlAttributes(New With {.class = "form-control"})
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(Function(m) m.LastName, New With {.class = "col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"})
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(m) m.LastName, htmlAttributes:=New With {Key .maxlength = "50", .class = "form-control"})
            </div>

            @Html.LabelFor(Function(m) m.FirstName, New With {.class = "col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"})
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(m) m.FirstName, htmlAttributes:=New With {Key .maxlength = "50", .class = "form-control"})
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(Function(m) m.IndividualDOB, New With {.class = "col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"})
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                @Html.Kendo.DatePickerFor(Function(m) m.IndividualDOB).Max(Date.Today).HtmlAttributes(New With {.class = "form-control", .maxlength = "10"})
            </div>

            @Html.Label("Residential County:", New With {.class = "col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"})
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                @Html.Kendo.DropDownListFor(Function(m) m.ResidentialCounty).BindTo(Model.ResidentialCountyOptions).OptionLabel("Select One").HtmlAttributes(New With {.class = "form-control"})
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 text-center submitButtons">
            @Html.Kendo.Button().Name("Clear").Content("Clear <i class='fa fa-times'></i>").HtmlAttributes(New With {.type = "submit", .name = "SubmitAction", .id = "clear", .value = "clear", .class = "btn-primary"})
            @Html.Kendo.Button().Name("Search").Content("Search <i class='fa fa-search'></i>").HtmlAttributes(New With {.type = "submit", .name = "SubmitAction", .id = "search", .value = "search", .class = "btn-green"})
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group text-center">
                 &nbsp;
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      @If Model.SearchResults Is Nothing Then
        @<div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group text-center complaintDetailButtons">
                @Html.Kendo.Button().Name("NoIndividual").Content("<span>Continue Without Selecting<br> an Individual</span> <i class='fa fa-arrow-right'></i>").HtmlAttributes(New With {.id = "btnNoIndividual", .class = "btn btn-primary btn-xl long-wrap", .value = "noindividual"})
            </div>
          </div>
       </div>

       End If

       @If (Model.SearchResults Is Nothing OrElse Model.SearchResults.Count = 0) AndAlso (Model.ProgramOffices IsNot Nothing AndAlso Model.ProgramOffices.Contains(EIM.BO.Enumerators.ProgramOffice.ODP)) AndAlso (Model.IsLicensed) Then
          @<div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12">   
          @Html.Kendo.Button().Name("NoMCI").ImageUrl(Url.Content("~/Content/Images/buttons/noMCI.jpg")).HtmlAttributes(New With {.id = "btnNoMCI", .value = "nomci"})
              </div>
          </div>
       End If

       @If Not Model.SearchResults Is Nothing AndAlso Model.SearchResults.Count > 0 Then
        @<div class="row" id="resultsGrid">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                 @(Html.Kendo.Grid(Of IndividualSearchResultViewModel)(Model.SearchResults).
                                Name("SearchIndivResults").
                                Sortable(Function(s) s.AllowUnsort(False)).
                                Filterable().
                                Scrollable(Sub(s) s.Height("100%")).
                                Columns(Sub(c)
                                            c.Bound(Function(m) m.MCI).ClientTemplate("<a href='' class='MCILink' id='#:MCI#_#:IndividualResultId#_#:ProgramOffice#'>#=MCI#</a>")
                                            c.Bound(Function(m) m.SSN)
                                            c.Bound(Function(m) m.Name).HtmlAttributes(New With {.class = "MCIName"})
                                            c.Bound(Function(m) m.DOB)
                                            c.Bound(Function(m) m.ResidentialCounty)
                                            c.Bound(Function(m) m.ProgramOffice)
                                            c.Bound(Function(m) m.WaiverName)
                                            c.Bound(Function(m) m.ProgramEffectiveDates)
                                            c.Bound(Function(m) m.SourceSystem).Hidden()
                                            c.Bound(Function(m) m.Line1).Hidden()
                                            c.Bound(Function(m) m.Line2).Hidden()
                                            c.Bound(Function(m) m.Line3).Hidden()
                                            c.Bound(Function(m) m.MI).Hidden()
                                            c.Bound(Function(m) m.Suffix).Hidden()
                                            c.Bound(Function(m) m.Gender).Hidden()
                                            c.Bound(Function(m) m.Phone).Hidden()
                                            c.Bound(Function(m) m.Email).Hidden()
                                            c.Bound(Function(m) m.City).Hidden()
                                            c.Bound(Function(m) m.State).Hidden()
                                            c.Bound(Function(m) m.Zip).Hidden()
                                            c.Bound(Function(m) m.FirstName).Hidden()
                                            c.Bound(Function(m) m.LastName).Hidden()
                                            c.Bound(Function(m) m.SourceSystemKey).Hidden()
                                            c.Bound(Function(m) m.IndividualResultId).Hidden()
                                            c.Bound(Function(m) m.SCEntityName).Hidden()
                                            c.Bound(Function(m) m.SCFirstName).Hidden()
                                            c.Bound(Function(m) m.SCLastName).Hidden()
                                            c.Bound(Function(m) m.SCPhone).Hidden()
                                            c.Bound(Function(m) m.HiddenDOB).Hidden()
                                            c.Bound(Function(m) m.FundingCounty).Hidden()
                                            c.Bound(Function(m) m.Region).Hidden()
                                            c.Bound(Function(m) m.BSU).Hidden()
                                            c.Bound(Function(m) m.AssignedSCUserID).Hidden()
                                            c.Bound(Function(m) m.AssignedSCSupervisorUserID).Hidden()

                                        End Sub).
                                DataSource(Sub(s) s.Ajax().ServerOperation(False)))
             </div>
          </div>
        End If

        @Html.HiddenFor(Function(m) m.Mode)
        @Html.Hidden("SelectedMciNum")
        @Html.Hidden("SelectedSSN")
        @Html.Hidden("SelectedName")
        @Html.Hidden("SelectedDOB")
        @Html.Hidden("SelectedFirstName")
        @Html.Hidden("SelectedLastName")
        @Html.HiddenFor(Function(m) m.FilingOrganizationFilter)

        <input type="hidden" id="CallingPage" name="CallingPage" value="@Model.CallingPage" />
     </div>

     End Using
   </div>


   <script type="text/javascript">

      $(document).ready(function () {

        $(this).keypress(function (e) {
          if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            $('#search').click();
            e.preventDefault();
          }
        })

      $("#Search").focus();

      $("#Identifier:text").on("focus", function () {
         var input = $(this);
         setTimeout(function () { input.select(); });
      });

      var errortext = "@Model.errorText"

      if(errortext != "")
        {
          var errorarray = errortext.split('~');
          var errormsg = "";
          for (var i = 0; i <errorarray.length; i++)
          {
            errormsg += errorarray[i] + '<br/>';
          }
          errortext = errormsg.substring(0, errormsg.length - 5);
        }
        $("#kendoValidatorField").html(errortext);

        var pageComingFrom = sessionStorage.getItem("pageComingFrom");
        var isPopUp = '@isPopupMode';

        if (pageComingFrom == "null" || isPopUp == 'Y') {
          var btnNoIndiv = $("#btnNoIndividual");
          btnNoIndiv.hide();
        }

        var filingOrganization = sessionStorage.getItem("filingOrganization");

        //clear sessionStorage
        sessionStorage.removeItem("filingOrganization");
        if (!filingOrganization) {
          filingOrganization = $("#FilingOrganization").val();
        }

    if (filingOrganization) {
          $("#FilingOrganizationFilter").val(filingOrganization);
    }


    $("div#IndividualSearchContent").on("click", "a.MCILink", function (e) {
        sessionStorage.setItem("IsContinueWithOutSelectingClicked", "No")
        if ($('#IndividualMCI') && $('#IndividualMCI').length > 0) {
            $('#IndividualMCI').val($(this).text());
            $('#IndividualMCIDiv').html($('#IndividualMCI')[0].value)
            $('#IndividualName').val($(this)[0].parentNode.nextSibling.nextSibling.innerText);
            $('#IndividualNameDiv').html($('#IndividualName')[0].value);
        }

        var dataToSend;
        var gridData = $("#SearchIndivResults").data("kendoGrid");
        if (gridData != null) {
            var selectedItem = this.id;

            var value = gridData._data.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < value; i++) {
                var item = gridData._data[i];
                var selectedItemRecord = item.MCI +'_'+ item.IndividualResultId+'_'+item.ProgramOffice
                if (selectedItemRecord == selectedItem) {
                    dataToSend = item;
                                           sessionStorage.setItem("selectedItemDOB", dataToSend.HiddenDOB.split(" ")[0])
                                           sessionStorage.setItem("selectedItemMCI", dataToSend.MCI)
                                           sessionStorage.setItem("selectedItemName", dataToSend.Name)
                                           sessionStorage.setItem("selectedItemProgEffDt", dataToSend.ProgramEffectiveDates)
                                           sessionStorage.setItem("selectedItemPO", dataToSend.ProgramOffice)
                                           sessionStorage.setItem("selectedItemSS", dataToSend.SourceSystem)
                                           sessionStorage.setItem("selectedItemSSKey", dataToSend.SourceSystemKey)
                                           sessionStorage.setItem("selectedItemSSN", dataToSend.SSN)
                                           sessionStorage.setItem("selectedItemWaiver", dataToSend.Waiver)

                                           sessionStorage.setItem("selectedItemLine1", dataToSend.Line1)
                                           sessionStorage.setItem("selectedItemLine2", dataToSend.Line2)
                                           sessionStorage.setItem("selectedItemLine3", dataToSend.Line3)
                                           sessionStorage.setItem("selectedItemMI", dataToSend.MI)
                                           sessionStorage.setItem("selectedItemSuffix", dataToSend.Suffix)
                                           sessionStorage.setItem("selectedItemGender", dataToSend.Gender)
                                           sessionStorage.setItem("selectedItemPhone", dataToSend.Phone)
                                           sessionStorage.setItem("selectedItemEmail", dataToSend.Email)
                                           sessionStorage.setItem("selectedItemCity", dataToSend.City)                                               
                                           sessionStorage.setItem("selectedItemCounty", dataToSend.ResidentialCounty)
                                           sessionStorage.setItem("selectedItemFundingCounty", dataToSend.FundingCounty)
                                           sessionStorage.setItem("selectedItemRegion", dataToSend.Region)
                                           sessionStorage.setItem("selectedItemState", dataToSend.State)
                                           sessionStorage.setItem("selectedItemZip", dataToSend.Zip)
                                           sessionStorage.setItem("selectedItemIndividualResultId", dataToSend.IndividualResultId)                                             
                                           sessionStorage.setItem("selectedItemSCEntityName", dataToSend.SCEntityName)
                                           sessionStorage.setItem("selectedItemSCFirstName", dataToSend.SCFirstName)
                                           sessionStorage.setItem("selectedItemSCLastName", dataToSend.SCLastName)
                                           sessionStorage.setItem("selectedItemSCPhone", dataToSend.SCPhone)
                                           sessionStorage.setItem("selectedItemHiddenDOB", dataToSend.HiddenDOB)
                                           sessionStorage.setItem("selectedBSU", dataToSend.BSU)
                                           sessionStorage.setItem("selectedAssignedSCUserID", dataToSend.AssignedSCUserID)
                                           sessionStorage.setItem("selectedAssignedSCSupervisorUserID", dataToSend.AssignedSCSupervisorUserID)

                }
            }
        }


        $("#SelectedMciNum").val($(this).text());
        if ($("#IndividualSearchWindow").data("kendoWindow")) {
          $("#IndividualSearchWindow").data("kendoWindow").close();
        }


        e.preventDefault();
      })

      $('#btnNoIndividual').click(function (e) {
         sessionStorage.setItem("IsContinueWithOutSelectingClicked", "Yes")
         window.location.href = baseUrl + "ComplaintIndividualInformation/Index";
      })

      $('#btnNoMCI').click(function (e) {
          window.location.href = baseUrl + "IndividualDetail/IndividualHasNoMCI";
      })

      ValidateTextDate();
   });

   </script>
```

P.S. The weirdest thing to me is that in IE9 it all displays as expected. But no luck in Chrome or FF.

I will really appreciate any help on this.

Comment: does chrome's console point out any errors ? Perhaps Fiddler will show an  erroneous request (chrome's network tab can do also) ?

Comment: That was the first thing I ran to. The only errors it shows are undefined JQueries which it makes sense since the <head> is empty. no reference to JQuery is rendering or any CSS or anything at all for that matter

Comment: Can you debug the razor in the view ?  The code flows ? Are there any exceptions thrown ?

Comment: is this line meant to have an "@"  @<div class="searchCriteriaDivCss @(If(isPopupMode = "Y", "hidden", ""))"> (just after the Ajax.BeginForm)? Also are you meant to be telling the page not to use the Layout if so are you including the relevant script files/ css files onto the page?

Comment: @Veverke I get an exception thrown JQuerry is undefined. But the Jquery is bundled in the Layout which is inherited by the search view. According t my MVC developers, the Layout is not to be inherited by the partial view (results page). It should inherit it from its main view (Search page)